# Servlet retrieve pre selected radio button

Tags: java, servlets

I pre select my radio buttons by the following code. The following inputs wrap in a form that post back to the same servlet.

```
buf.append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\""+ FTNAME+ "\" " + (FTNAME.equals("Arial") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">Arial &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
buf.append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\""+ FTNAME+ "\" " + (FTNAME.equals("Serif") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">Serif &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
buf.append("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\""+ FTNAME+ "\" " + (FTNAME.equals("SansSerif") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">SansSerif <br><br>");
```

However, when I try to do

```
FTNAME = request.getParameter("FTNAME") == null ? "Arial" : request.getParameter("FTNAME"); //Arial as font name default
```

to get my FTNAME, it always return what it was set from the code above, not my new selection.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're setting your value as Arial for all three radio buttons. So no matter what radio button you choose it will always return you arial.

This how your html page would look like:

```
<input type="radio" name="FTNAME" value="Arial" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="FTNAME" value="Arial">
<input type="radio" name="FTNAME" value="Arial">
```

And you servlet `request.getParameter("FTNAME")` would alway return you the value "Arial". You need to change to something like this

```
buf.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\"Arial\"" + (FTNAME.equals("Arial") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">Arial &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
buf.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\"Serif\""+ (FTNAME.equals("Serif") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">Serif &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp");
buf.println("<input type=\"radio\" name=\"FTNAME\" value=\"SansSerif\""+ (FTNAME.equals("SansSerif") ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") + ">SansSerif <br><br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes: My suggestion is you'd better read the HTML code produced by your servlet. You'll find that all three radios have THE SAME VALUE.

Comment: No, the FTNAME is a parameter entered by user. If the user chooses "Arial", then only the Arial radio button will be checked, the check status of the other two buttons would be null. My question is "the Arial button has been checked by the previous history, if i want to choose Serif, the check status of Arial will remain the same. How can it return a new value?"